# PHP Wildcard to display all values of variable

Tags: php, wordpress, sorting, wildcard, custom-post-type

We have set up custom post types for real estate properties and a search form to search through these custom post types using price, city, newest, etc. We are using query variable strings/if statements to display the results, but we are having trouble with the sort options. We have three sort options in place : Newest, Price Low-High, and Price High-Low.

When the default results are displayed, the sort does not work correctly, but when a city is set in the search dropdown, the sort works perfectly.

For the city search, we have this code in place:

```
if (isset($_POST['city'])) {
    $qs_city = get_query_var('city');
}
else {
    $qs_city = " ";
```

I believe that this is due to the `else` portion of the code above. We need some sort of wildcard that allows all cities listed to be listed if a city is not set. We have tried several different things, but nothing seems to work. I'm fairly new to this, so I can better clarify any of the above, if necessary.

This is the code used to sort:

```
if (isset($_POST['sort'])) {
    $qs_sort = get_query_var('sort');
    switch ($qs_sort) {
        case 'newest':
            $args = array( 
            'post_type' => 'residential', 
            'posts_per_page' => 10,
            'paged' => $paged,
            'orderby' => 'L_StatusDate',
            'order' => 'DESC',
            'meta_query' => array(
                           array(
                                'key' => 'L_City',
                                'value' => $qs_city,
                                'compare' => 'LIKE'
                           ),
                           array(
                                'key' => 'L_SystemPrice',
                                'value'   => array( $qs_price_min, $qs_price_max ),
                                'type'    => 'numeric',
                                'compare' => 'BETWEEN'
                           ),
                           array(
                               'key' => 'LM_Int1_2',
                               'value' => $qs_beds,
                               'compare' => '>='
                           ),
                           array(
                               'key' => 'LM_Int1_3',
                               'value' => $qs_baths,
                               'compare' => '>='
                           )
                       )
           );
        break;
        case 'price-low':
            $args = array( 
            'post_type' => 'residential', 
            'posts_per_page' => 10,
            'paged' => $paged,
            'orderby' => 'L_SystemPrice',
            'order' => 'ASC',
            'meta_query' => array(
                            array(
                                'key' => 'L_City',
                                'value' => $qs_city,
                                'compare' => 'LIKE'
                           ),
                           array(
                                'key' => 'L_SystemPrice',
                                'value'   => array( $qs_price_min, $qs_price_max ),
                                'type'    => 'numeric',
                                'compare' => 'BETWEEN'
                           ),
                           array(
                               'key' => 'LM_Int1_2',
                               'value' => $qs_beds,
                               'compare' => '>='
                           ),
                           array(
                               'key' => 'LM_Int1_3',
                               'value' => $qs_baths,
                               'compare' => '>='
                           )
                       )
           );
        break;
        case 'price-high':
            $args = array( 
            'post_type' => 'residential', 
            'posts_per_page' => 10,
            'paged' => $paged,
            'orderby' => 'L_SystemPrice',
            'order' => 'DESC',
            'meta_query' => array(
                           //'relation'    => 'AND',
                           array(
                                'key' => 'L_City',
                                'value' => $qs_city,
                                'compare' => 'LIKE'
                           ),
                           array(
                                'key' => 'L_SystemPrice',
                                'value'   => array( $qs_price_min, $qs_price_max ),
                                'type'    => 'numeric',
                                'compare' => 'BETWEEN'
                           ),
                           array(
                               'key' => 'LM_Int1_2',
                               'value' => $qs_beds,
                               'compare' => '>='
                           ),
                           array(
                               'key' => 'LM_Int1_3',
                               'value' => $qs_baths,
                               'compare' => '>='
                           )
                       )
           );
        break;
    }
}
else {
    $args = array( 
            'post_type' => 'residential', 
            'posts_per_page' => 10,
            'paged' => $paged,
            'meta_query' => array(
                           //'relation'    => 'AND',
                           array(
                               'key' => 'L_StatusDate',
                               'orderby' => 'DESC'
                               //set default to sort by newest
                           ),
                           array(
                                'key' => 'L_City',
                                'value' => $qs_city,
                                'compare' => 'LIKE'
                           ),
                           array(
                                'key' => 'L_SystemPrice',
                                'value'   => array( $qs_price_min, $qs_price_max ),
                                'type'    => 'numeric',
                                'compare' => 'BETWEEN'
                           ),
                           array(
                               'key' => 'LM_Int1_2',
                               'value' => $qs_beds,
                               'compare' => '>='
                           ),
                           array(
                               'key' => 'LM_Int1_3',
                               'value' => $qs_baths,
                               'compare' => '>='
                           )
                       )
           );
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The main question for your situation is "what kind of application will sort the results?". It looks like you use some kind on database. But which one? If it's SQL-like database, - just replace `$qs_city = " "` with `$qs_city = "%";`

Comment: yes, we use my sql for the database. When we use %, the default results show nothing until a city is selected in the search form. We would like to show all cities by default.

Comment: @courtneyGCM, the answer is exactly what you needed for. It's the wildcard you asked. None of code provided by you includes real transformation of parameters into SQL query. But In SQL query (MySQL in your case), the wildcard is % sign.  If it doesn't work for you, this means that you have another code in your project that you should check. Look at the real SQL query with proposed changes with "%" sign